# How can I style a React component that does not use Material UI elements with Material UIs style system?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Material UIs (MUI's) documentation is perfectly broken here: At
https://mui.com/system/getting-started/overview/#all-inclusive
the last line reads:

*"See ->Advanced for details on how to use MUI System with non-MUI components."*

Yet the link to Advanced is dead as of today (404). Is there a way to use the style system outside of MUIs components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's the [Custom Components](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/custom-components/) page, it was fixed [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/pull/33867) but not live yet I guess

Comment: mark answered pls

Comment: the docu there is outdated, the typescript example does not work. yet the hint was very good.

Comment: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/29723 helped with typescript